# Can i have same activity using different xml file

Tags: android

I'm creating an android app that will have multiple pages with the same layout, but the only thing that changes will be a string that is displayed on the top (using setText). Can I use a different xml file in the same activity class.., or does Android not allow that?

Comment: look here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377446/in-android-can-i-have-different-activities-use-the-same-xml-file

Comment: but here they have use sane activity and call different xml layout within that activity..but in my case i want opposite to that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with that. You can use in the same activity as many XML layouts as you want. Simply switch between them using `setContentView()`

Comment: how that can be done..can you send me a simple example for that..one more thing is it possible to use setcontentView in another function instead of onCreate function

Comment: @Anshuman: put it wherever you want... Myselft using setContentView on various places not only in onCreate() for instance in onClick()